# How to bind event with all bootstrap accordion

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have multiple **accordion** in my page. Now I want to bind some event on expand of each **accordion**. But the event is getting binded with the first accordion only.

**HTML is: The following accordion is generated multiple times by a loop.**

```
<div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" href="#someId_indexOfLoop" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse">
                    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> someText
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-up pull-right"></i>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="someId_indexOfLoop" aria-expanded="false" style="">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="project-section activity">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled activity-list" id="ul_someId_indexOfLoop">
                    // here <li></li> are generated by ajax response
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And here is the .js code where I am binding the event**

```
 $('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function(e){
    var ulId  = $(e.target).attr('id');
    // some code like alert('hi');
});
```

And here the alert is coming on expand of the first accordion only, the event is not getting bind with all the accordion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID of an element must be unique, the id selector will return only the first element with the given id so use class instead of id

```
<div class="panel-group accordion">
```

then

```
$('.accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function(e){
    var ulId  = $(e.target).attr('id');
    // some code like alert('hi');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't set the same ID to more than one element, the ID selector can only return one element for a specific ID.
You should add something in common to all accordions, eg:
Add a class 'accordion' to all accordions and select with `$('.accordion')`
You could also add a data attribute to each accordion, like:
data-isAccordion and select with `$('div[data-isAccordion]')`

Answer (score 1):

According to the HTML Specification, ID attribute is a unique selector. If you want to select multiple elements on a page, use class.

I would recommend using event bubbling to subscribe to events rather than using class to select and subscribe to events. Event bubbling is very straight forward concept. Here's an example, using your code: http://jsbin.com/yirazo/1/edit?html,js,output

I'm not attaching any event listeners to specific accordions. I'm just catching those events as they bubble up through the DOM.